# How to convert Java Collection[Int] to Array[Int] in Scala

Tags: java, scala, treemap

I have a `java.util.Treemap[Long, Int]` in Scala. What I need to do is convert the values in the Treemap into an Array[Int].

I can either get an `Iterator[Int]` or `Collection[Int]` from the `TreeMap`, but I'm not sure how to convert these into an `Array[Int]`.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with `t.values.toArray` is that `java.util.Collection` already has a `toArray()` method, which is why it returns an `Integer[]` which looks like an `Array[AnyRef]` to Scala. If Java didn't have such a method, the implicit in `JavaConversions` would kick in and covert it to to an `Iterable[Int]` before building the Array. So you can either call the coversion explicitly or give a type hint:

```
import collection.JavaConversions._    

(t.values: Iterable[Int]).toArray
```

or alternatively

```
import collection.JavaConverters._

t.values.asScala.toArray
```

On my machine these are <s>over twice</s> about 30 times as fast as using `toMap`, for a 1000-entry TreeMap.

Comment: Another trick, instead of using a type hint, to get it to perform the implicit conversion to `Iterable[Int]` would be to explicitly supply the implicit ClassManifest argument: `t.values.toArray(manifest[Int])`

Answer (score 2):

I never worked with Scala but in Java, you coud use `Collection.toArray()` method to get an int[].

Hope it's help.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
import collection.JavaConversions._

val treemap = new java.util.TreeMap[Long, Int]()
treemap.put(1,1)
treemap.put(2,2)

treemap.toMap.values.toArray // res0: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2)
```

This converts the `TreeMap` to a scala `Map`, gets the values, and converts them to an `Array`.

Unfortunately `treemap.values.toArray` doesn't do the trick, because the implicit conversion from `java.util.Collection[Int]` when you call `.toArray` gives you back `Array[Object]`.

Comment: This gives you an array of objects, not an array of integers